# Quickly set values in map over range C++

Tags: c++, stl, assign, stdmap

I need to set all the values in a map within a range of `(0,N)` to `false`. When I simply iterate over the range and set the value, it is rather slow, with the below example taking about 300 microseconds.

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<int, bool> mp;
int N = 600;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    mp[i] = false;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139325/setting-all-values-in-a-stdmap

Comment: Could you split up the range and then use `std::async`?

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to optimize if you mention what you are using the map for.

Comment: Do you really need a map here? Seems like a `std::vector` or even `std::array` would do quite well here.

Comment: This is not what maps are for, so it's not surprising that this is a comparatively inefficent process. There is no "faster way to do this", this is how maps work. They are not designed for this.

Comment: the fast way is not to do it at all. Eg you do not need to initialize before `mp[i] == false` will result in `true`. Its not clear what you need it for, but I am almost certain that you actually do not need it

Answer (score -1):

The version below takes advantage of the fact that you can to this in parallel. [async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) executes the tasks in a separate thread (also see [launch-policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch)).

The sequential approach takes 0.016s and the parallel approach takes 0.006s.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <future>

// end exclusive
void set_m(int begin, int end, std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, bool>> mp)
{
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++)
    {
        mp->insert({i, false});
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto mp = std::make_shared<std::map<int, bool>>();
    // takes 0m0.016s
    set_m(0, 6000 + 1, mp);

    // takes 0m0.006s
    std::vector<std::future<void>> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i += 1000)
    {
        v.push_back(std::async(set_m, i, i + 1001, mp));
    }
    for (std::future<void> &a : v)
    {
        a.wait();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a data race? You have multiple threads attempting to modify the same container. Standard library containers aren't thread-safe.

Comment: The parallel version **doesn't do anything**. The map is already filled at this point. Because of this no elements get actually inserted and nothing actually happens. If you insert a `mp->clear();` you will see that the parallel version causes race conditions and thus undefined behaviour and thus is missing several entries. You would need to synchronize access, but then you end up with a serial code with a huge overhead for synchronization.

Comment: Good to know. How does this code cause a data race? I am inserting in at different keys in the map after all..

Comment: Assuming `std::map` is implemented as a balanced binary tree, adding or removing elements can cause the tree to need rebalancing. Multiple writers while the data structure is being reorganized is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Okay. Makes total sense. Sorry for this answer.